# Can you SHA1 hash a file to a certain length

Tags: php, hash, sha

I need to compare two files. One file may be longer than the other and I need to check to see if the longer file contains all of the data of the shorter file. 
I could do a binary compare of the two something like this:

```
function compareFiles($file_a, $file_b){
  if (filesize($file_a) > filesize($file_b)){
    $fp_a = fopen($file_b, 'rb');
    $fp_b = fopen($file_a, 'rb');
  } else { // filesize($file_b) > filesize($file_a)
    $fp_a = fopen($file_a, 'rb');
    $fp_b = fopen($file_b, 'rb');
  }
  while (($b = fread($fp_a, 4096)) !== false){
    $b_b = fread($fp_b, 4096);
    if ($b !== $b_b){
      fclose($fp_a);
      fclose($fp_b);
      return false;
    }
  }
  fclose($fp_a);
  fclose($fp_b);
  return true;
}
```

but this would be slow. As an alternative, I could compare the SHA1 hash of the smaller file against the SHA1 hash of the larger file up and until the size of the smaller file, something like this:

```
function compareFiles($file_a, $file_b){
  $tmpfile = '/dev/shm/tmp_file_copy.bin';
  if (filesize($file_a) > filesize($file_b)){
    $readfromfile = $file_b;
    $bytes_to_copy = filesize($file_b);
  } else {
    $readfromfile = $file_a
    $bytes_to_copy = filesize($file_a);
  }
  $readfile = fopen($readfromfile, 'rb');
  $writefile = fopen($tmpfile, 'wb');
  while (!feof($readfile) && $bytes_to_copy> 0) {
    if ($bytes_to_copy <= 8192) {
      $contents = fread($readfile, $bytes_to_copy);
      $bytes_to_copy = 0;
    } else {
      $contents = fread($readfile, 8192);
      $bytes_to_copy =- 8192;
    }
    fwrite($writefile, $contents);
  }
  fclose($writefile);
  fclose($readfile);
  $result = sha1_file($readfromfile = $file_a ? $file_b : $file_a) === sha1_file($tmpfile);
  unlink($tmpfile);
  return $result;
}
```

but I fear that this would also be slow as it involves a lot of I/O (to /dev/shm).

In short, I'm looking for a better way...

Comment: whats the required output from the compare?

Comment: Output is true or false. Either the content of the files up to the length of the shorter file matches or it doesnt.

Comment: you can use fread to get the whole file up to byte X for the compare, you dont need to loop it in chunks

Comment: Yes, but chunking it is a bit more fail safe in my opinion. I could have added retries in there too, but that would make a bit more complicated and mislead  the reader from the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing the files in this case will only be slower. Consider the following case.

File `A.txt` contents:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

File `B.txt` contents:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```

<sub>Note that `A.txt` is 40 characters total, 10 characters longer than `B.txt` at 30 characters</sub>

How much I/O do we have to do on each file to determine if `A.txt` contains all of `B.txt`? 40 bytes? 30 bytes? No, the answer is only 20 bytes, because that's how much the two files share have in common. You stream each file one byte (or chunk of bytes) at a time and compare them as you go. The results of such a comparison looks like this:

```
A.txt: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

B.txt: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB

Stream ---------------------^
Result ✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓X
```

And then you stop. Why compare the rest?

If you hash both files, you have to have the whole contents in memory to compute the hash. Even if you hash them in chunks while streaming them into memory, which do you think is faster: comparing each byte from each file or hashing the chunk? The complexity of the comparison is `O(number of bytes)` whereas the complexity of the SHA-1 hash algorithm is specified by [RFC 3174](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174).

Comment: yep I agree that compareFiles will be more efficient as it stops the compare at the point where either the filesize of the smaller file is reached OR where the files differ. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you liked the answer @Greg. Please push the green check mark to accept if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The byte-by-byte is the best method in your case. It only compares first *x* bytes of both files and stops if they are different. Hash function must process all bytes in file. Isn't that slower?